# How do I use the smallest amount database file space to rebuild an index on Mircosoft SQL Server Express due to the 10GB limit

Tags: sql-server, disk-space, index-maintenance

How do I use the smallest amount of database file space to rebuild an index on Mircosoft SQL Server Express due to the 10GB limit

I have a database file size of 7GB but I have two indexes that are on the two largest tables that are very fragmented
[image]

If I try to rebuild the index PK_Sale_Dtl the file size balloons to 10GB and the rebuild fails and I get nowhere but if I drop the index and recreate it the file doesn't barely increase at all

Why is this? And which is better rebuild or recreate index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that index rebuild means creating a new index under covers and *then* dropping the old index. I.e., while the operation is running you need twice the amount of storage available. If that isn't doable for you, you have basically two options:

Do it yourself in the opposite order: Drop first and *then* create.

Or do REORGANIZE instead of REBUILD.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is this?? And which is better rebuild or receate index??

Rebuilding an index leaves the existing index in place, builds a new one, and drops the old one.

So if you don't need to have the index available for queries during the rebuild, drop/create or disable it before rebuilding it.

Disabling an index is just like dropping it, but you don't have to remember the index DDL.  eg

```
alter index ix_SomeIndex on SomeTable disable;
alter index ix_SomeIndex on SomeTable rebuild;
```

Comment: Disabling an index does leave it's associated statistics object available though (and it will continue to be updated).